# Linking PHP Sheet

Tags: php

I recently tried to link a PHP and HTML sheet, yet receive weird output.

My HTML Code is as follows:

```
<html>

<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="text" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value = "Submit">

</form>

</html>
```

My PHP code is as such:

```
    <html>

    <head>
            <title>Information gathered </title>
    </head>


    <body>
        <?php 
            echo "<p>Data processed</p>"; 
        ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

When I click submit, it generates a new page with the following output:

> Data processed"; ?>

Where does the ' "; ?> ' at the end of my string come from?

Comment: are you sure, the php code is processed?

Comment: What do you mean by "processed"?

Comment: Are you running an HTTP server configured to parse PHP scripts?

Comment: @alexp2603 have a look at the linked page